# How to set echo mysql_fetch_array to horizontal?

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

This code load from mysql data based on varchar 'group' to table and put picture in each of them. It is working but result is vertical album but I want horizontal.

```
<?php 
include "../script/connect_to_mysql.php";
if (isset($_GET['a'])) {
    $ge = $_GET['a'];   
    $tisk = "";
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM lch WHERE  `group` = '$ge' ");
    $productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
    if ($productCount > 0) {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
            $id = $row["id"];
            $name = $row["name"];
            $tisk .='<table width="120" height="120" ><br>
                <tr><br>
                    <td height="118" colspan="2"><br><img src="../lch/ikon/' . $id . '.jpg" alt=' . $name . ' width="100" height="100" /><br>;</td>
</table>';<br>      
        }<br>
     }<br>

echo "$tisk";<br>

}<br>
?>
```

---

LOL I can post my own answer. I found solution what working for me. Here I am posting it. Anyway thanks for help :-P

---

```
    include "../script/connect_to_mysql.php";

    if (isset($_GET['a'])) {
       $ge = $_GET['a'];
       $tisk = "";
       $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM lch WHERE  `group` = '$ge' ");
       $productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
 if ($productCount > 0) {

     $tisk = '<table width="120" height="120"><tr>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

    $id = $row["id"];
    $name = $row["name"];
    $tisk .='<td height="118" colspan="2"><img src="../lch/ikon/' . $id . '.jpg" alt="$name" width="100" height="100" /></td>';
 }

 echo '<table width="120" height="120">
 <tdbody>
    <tr>
    ' .$tisk. '
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>         
 ';
  }

  }
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sort-of fixed your post, SO certainly does let you post tables within code. (I left in what might be syntax errors)

Assuming that the `<br>`s are an artifact of your posting messy code in the editor, you simply need to move the `<tr></tr>` outside the loop.

```
if ($productCount > 0) {
    $tisk = '<table><tr>';
    while(row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $id = $row["id"];
        $name = $row["name"];
        $tisk .='<td><img src="../lch/ikon/' . $id . '.jpg" alt=' . $name . ' width="100" height="100" /></td>';
     }
     $tisk = '</tr></table>';
     echo $tisk;
}
```

This will produce a table with all the cells in the same row, instead of a bunch of tables with all one column each.

If you then want a certain number per row, you'll need to use modulo:

```
if ($productCount > 0) {
    $cellCount = 0;
    $tisk = '<table><tr>';
    while(row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $cellCount++;
        if($cellCount%5==0){
          $tisk .= '</tr><tr>';
        }
        $id = $row["id"];
        $name = $row["name"];
        $tisk .='<td><img src="../lch/ikon/' . $id . '.jpg" alt=' . $name . ' width="100" height="100" /></td>';
     }
     $tisk = '</tr></table>';
     echo $tisk;
}
```

Comment: sry that does not work , nothing appear. :-/